# PostSharp in web project using NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package, postsharp

After I followed the steps listed here : http://doc.postsharp.net//postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/41129237-a5d4-4acf-aef4-c46759ccfb4b.htm

it gives me this error : "
PostSharp is not introduced in the build process. If NuGet just restored the PostSharp package, you need to rebuild the solution."

Do you have any ideea why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you rebuilt your solution, as it says? And if so, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes, I still got the error after rebuilding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `RequiresPostSharp.cs` file was meant to be helpful, but does not always work correctly. If PostSharp is otherwise working, you can [safely delete that file](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/268-postsharp-is-not-introduced-in-the-build-process).